# Consider $g_n(x)= \sqrt{x^2+1/n}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $n$ be a natural number. Find the limit $g(x)$ of $g_n(x)$. Is the convergence uniform?

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider $g_n(x)= \sqrt{x^2+1/n}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $n$ be a natural number. Find the pointwise limit $g(x)$ of $g_n(x)$. Is the convergence uniform?

So if I did it correctly, I got the pointwise convergence to be a piecewise function. So g(x) is 1 (if x=1,-1) and g(x) is x (if -1<x<1). The thing I'm having some trouble with is understanding how to show if this is uniformly convergent on the interval [-1,1]. From what I understand, this wouldn't be uniformly convergent because the pointwise convergence function is not continuous. I am supposed to use the definition of uniformly convergent to show this. I don't need to do a proof for the question but just explain why it is or is not uniformly convergent. As I said earlier, I don't think it is uniformly convergent since g(x) isn't continuous (assuming I found this function correctly).

Comment: Pointwise convergence is $|x|$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$

Comment: What is the difference between proving that something is true and explaining that something is true?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I should have added "formal" proof. My question sounds redundant

Comment: @QC_QAOA Whoops. I was over thinking but this would make it easier to go forward and understand